# Sending csv file from Flask API along with json response

Tags: python, flask, jsonresponse

Hi So I have to send json response from my Flask API including the file, so earlier I was using this for sending the json response

```
@app.route('/idea123',methods=['POST','GET'])
def func123():
    try:
        DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY=r'../../..'
        d1={}
        result_file = abcd(file)
        d1['Status']='Success'
        d1['Created_date']=datetime.now() 
        #return send_from_directory(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY, result_file)   
        return d1

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        d1['Status']='Failure'
        d1['Created_date']=datetime.now()
        return d1
```

Later I had to send the result file along with json response, how can i send both in same response?
I have commented the file that needs to be send code

Mentioned the code above

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can use like this :

`return {'d1_array': d1, 'result_json': result_file}`

Answer (score 0):

JSON is sent as a string on the network. Meanwhile, files are sent as a stream. It has a different response format, you can't send it in the same response.
Alternatively, you can put your files somewhere people can download them, such as your cloud storage or your server's public directory. Then, you can put your response with the file address, so that your front-end can download it.

```
@app.route('/excel',methods=['GET'])
def func123():
    try:
        DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY='/static/files.csv'
        return {'status':'success', 'file': DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY}
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return {'status':'fail', 'file':''}
```